# Unable to write the data to databricks delta table

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, amazon-s3, databricks

I am trying to create a table in data bricks using data which is in parquet format but before that, i need to convert the datatypes of that data to data bricks compatible so I converted them but, I'm unable to write the converted data to databricks delta format

Here is the code I wrote in databricks to convert the datatypes and to write the data into databricks delta format:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, ArrayType
```

### Define the schema for the input data

```py
input_schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("array_column", ArrayType(IntegerType()), True),
    StructField("set_column", StringType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True)   
])
```

### Read the input data from S3

```py
input_data = spark.read \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .option("inferSchema", "false") \
  .schema(input_schema) \
  .parquet("/mnt/employee/employee_data/complex.parquet")
```

### Convert the data types to be compatible with Databricks

```
converted_data = input_data.withColumn("id", input_data["id"].cast(IntegerType())) \
  .withColumn("array_column", input_data["array_column"].cast(ArrayType(StringType()))) \
  .withColumn("set_column", input_data["set_column"].cast(StringType())) \
  .withColumn("name", input_data["name"].cast(StringType())) \
```

### Write the converted data to Databricks Delta format

```py
converted_data.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/mnt/data")
```

This is the error I am getting :

[image]

This is my data:

[image]

Comment: try adding the file name of converted data `converted_data.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/mnt/delta/converted_data")`

Comment: not working i have tried this also, `converted_data.write.saveAsTable("complex_table", mode="overwrite")` , still not working

Comment: Try using BIGINT  or LONG type instead of INT in variable - input_schema

Comment: not working ,`com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file dbfs:/mnt/employee/employee_data/complex.parquet. Parquet column cannot be converted. Column: [array_column], Expected: ArrayType(LongType,true), Found: BINARY`